# SQL Query - find with all NULLS

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table that has Usename and Site information:

```
Username   Site
jbrown     NULL
jbrown     NULL
jbrown     NULL
msmith     3
msmith     12
msmith     NULL 
ptodd      18
ptodd      16 
ptodd      NULL
jdrem      3
jdrem      NULL
jdrem      NULL
```

What I need to do is fetch usernames that have ALL NULLS for their site or ones that ANY Site that is 3. So in this case the output would be:

```
jbrown
msmith
jdrem
```

Note that ptodd was not in the end result as their were no sites that had 3.

I was considering a group by but not sure how to say ALL NULLS or ANY that are 3 based on Username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and conditional aggregation.

```
select username
from tablename
group by username
having count(*)=count(case when site is null then 1 end) 
or count(case when site=3 then 1 end)>=1
```

Comment: Hi Vkp, thank you for your response. Seems to work. One question I have  is that for an username set, how does the code you wrote choose for ALL nulls? I see how it does for any that are site=3 but not how it does for ALL nulls as is the case for jbrown.

Comment: Keep in mind we can have a situation for a given user where it is NULL, 13, 14 in which case it is NULL but NOT ALL are NULLS.

Comment: @NatePet .. `count(*)` is the total rows per user, `count(case when site is null then 1 end) ` counts all the `null` values per user (all other values are ignored for count)..if they are equal it means the user has all null values for site. In case a user has NULL, 13, 14 count(*)=3, null count=1..the first condition fails..also the user doesn't have a site=3 row..so the second condition fails too. Hence that user won't be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might be too similar to other to count but..

```
SELECT   [Username] 
FROM     Table
GROUP BY [Username]
HAVING   MAX([Site]) IS NULL OR 
         COUNT(CASE WHEN [Site] = 3 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you. How does the MAX work such that it pulls all the nulls for a given username

Comment: if all of the values are null for a Username.. Then `MAX([Site]) IS NULL` returns true.. The OR condition handles your your other requirement `ones that ANY Site that is 3`

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation will probably be faster, but here is another option:

using `not exists(...) or Site = 3`:

```
select distinct Username
from t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from t as i
  where i.username = t.username
    and i.site is not null
    )
  or Site = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use what I call the "better than" sql principal.  Where you make sure there is nothing "better than".

```
select username, site 
from table_name t
left join table_name betterThan on betterThan.site is not null and betterThan.username = t.username and betterThan.id <> t.id
where (t.site is null or t.site = 3) and betterThan.id is null;
```